# Can I total sum each row in the table and then disabled it with a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some trouble with my code. The problem is when I use `each()`, it loop from the first cell to the end of the row and get every value from it.
I just want it to get the value from each row and then when I give it a specific number it will calculate the total and print at the end of the row.
When I clicked the checkbox the `input` will be enabled and when I clicked again it will be disabled and the text in its with the total sum also disappear

```js
function de() {
  document.getElementById('check1').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('text1').disabled = !this.checked;
  };
  document.getElementById('check2').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('text2').disabled = !this.checked;
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:text").change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("#productbody tr").each(function(index, tr) {
      var price = $(tr).find("td:eq(2)").text();
      var amount = $("input:text").val();
      if ($("input:text").val() > 0) {
        sum = parseInt(price) * amount;
        $(tr).find("td:eq(4)").text(tong);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="product" class="class">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>amount</td>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="productbody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="check1" onClick="de()" />
      </td>
      <td>iPhone9</td>
      <td>700</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text1" disabled /></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="check2" onClick="de()" />
      </td>
      <td>Samsung Star</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td><input id="text2" disabled></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pa9hywex/1/

I expect the output was about total sum each row when I give the amount number to that row. But actually, it also gives the result to the second row which I haven't checked the checkbox to enable the `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#productbody tr").find("input:text").change(function() {
    var tong = 0;
    var price = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2)").text();
    var amount = $(this).val();
    if (amount > 0) {
      tong = parseInt(price) * amount;
      $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(4)").text(tong);
    }
  });
});
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/vjna2cy7/

Answer (score 0):

Your for each should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

$("input:text").change(function() {

```
$("#productbody tr").each(function(index, tr) {
var tong = 0;
  var price = $(tr).find("td:eq(2)").text();
  var amount =parseInt($(tr).find("input:text").val());
  if (amount > 0) {
    tong = parseInt(price) * amount;
    $(tr).find("td:eq(4)").text(tong);

    }
   });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are needlessly iterating through all the rows when only the amount of a single row has changed. What you are looking here is the **context** of the calculation: in this case, the context is the closest `<tr>` element, and you want to perform calculations using information in that row only.

Therefore, in the change event of the input, all you need is:

1. Get the parent table row. This is done by using `$(this).closest('tr')`
2. Get the price and amount from the correct columns of the row. Instead of using `parseInt()`, you can use the unary operator `+` to convert a string to number.

This should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:text").change(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $total = $row.find('td:eq(4)');
    var price = +$row.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var amount = +this.value;
    
    $total.text(price * amount);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="product" class="class">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>amount</td>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="productbody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="check1" onClick="de()" />
      </td>
      <td>iPhone9</td>
      <td>700</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text1" disabled /></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="check2" onClick="de()" />
      </td>
      <td>Samsung Star</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td><input id="text2" disabled></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  function de() {

    document.getElementById('check1').onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById('text1').disabled = !this.checked;
    };
    document.getElementById('check2').onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById('text2').disabled = !this.checked;
    };

  }

</script>
```